# How to draw Marker and route between two geo points taken from ListView item?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, google-maps-api-3

I have task. I have to display messages from a specific Mobile number on a `ListView` in one activity. These Messages contains Latitude and Longitude of two Locations. When I click any of the List item it should draw markers on that two locations and have to draw route between them in another activity.
My Message format is !+11.3326,+077.7193,08:41!+11.3326,+077.7194,08:41#

My MainActivity.java is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<String> msgList=getSMS();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,msgList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String lat1=str.substring(2,8);
            String lng1=str.substring(11,18);
            String lat2=str.substring(27,33);
            String lng2=str.substring(36,43);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lat1+""+lng1+""+lat2+""+lng2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public List<String> getSMS(){
    List<String>sms=new ArrayList<String>();
    final String SMS_URI_INBOX="content://sms/inbox";
    try {
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
        String[] projection=new String[]{"_id","address","person","body","date","type"};
        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,"address='+918870346164'",null,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int index_Address = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
            int index_Person = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");
            int index_Body = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
            int index_Date = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
            int index_Type = cursor.getColumnIndex("type");
            do {
                String strAddress = cursor.getString(index_Address);
                int intPerson = cursor.getInt(index_Person);
                String strBody = cursor.getString(index_Body);
                String longDate = cursor.getString(index_Date);
                int intType = cursor.getInt(index_Type);

                sms.add("\n"+strBody+"\n");
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            if (!cursor.isClosed()){
                cursor.close();
                cursor=null;
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        Log.d("SQLiteException",e.getMessage());
    }
    return sms;
}
```

My MapsActivity.java is
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    addMarker();

}

private void addMarker() {
    final LatLng latLng=new LatLng(lat1,lng1);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Marker"));
}
```

I have displayed the messages and can be able to get inputs from `ListView` item. I don't know how to pass those `lat1`, `lng1`, `lat2`, `lng2` values to `MapsActivity` and add Markers. Any solutions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch your map activity pass the latlng values in your intent.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("locationValues",str);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

now in your on create of Maps activity get those values back.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    String locationString = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("locationValues","");
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(locationString))
    {
        String lat1=str.substring(2,8);
        String lng1=str.substring(11,18);
        String lat2=str.substring(27,33);
        String lng2=str.substring(36,43);
        addMarker(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2);
    }
```

}

```
 private void addMarker(String lat1,String lng1,String lat2,String lng2) {
     //you can use those value here then.
     final LatLng latLng=new LatLng(lat1,lng1);
     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My      Marker"));
 }
```